# Processing get higher max frameRate

Tags: processing.js

So I just recently kind of had a breakthrough in Neural Nets and made a couple of games with NN AI's. For training, I use `frameRate(100000)` to jack the frame rate up. However, checking with `println(frameRate)` I see that the average frame rate is about 270. Removing all displays (drawing shapes pretty much) increases it to about 300.

I'd like to make it faster, I noticed the documentation states the `frameRate()` only goes as high as your processor can handle, but checking with task manager I see the program is only using about 20% of my CPU and only 90MB. I've increased the maximum available memory to 4096MB in preferences, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

So I guess my question is, how do I allow processing to use more of my CPU for faster frameRate [or is there a better option other than simply "optimizing my code", because its already fairly optimized IMO (not saying it couldn't be better though)].

Comment: Are you using Processing or Processing.js? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Also remember what you're asking the computer to do: a framerate of 100000 frames per second means one frame every 1/100000th of a second, or once every 10μs. There is no way that your computer can run frame boostrapping, line printing, and then frame code cleanup, that fast. Also remember what your framerate is for: it's for drawing frames. If you need to do something that isn't graphic drawing, at a faster interval, don't tie it to your framerate. Turn off fixed framerate animation, and use a custom timing class/package/etc instead, to trigger `redraw()` only when there's something to redraw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that even with a very high framerate, the mechanisms that call `draw()` have some overhead that you don't need if you aren't drawing anything. Your computer might limit the frame rate depending on your graphics settings. Also note that the `println()` statement itself is very slow, so you should not use it for continuously printing out your frame rate.

If you aren't drawing anything (or if you're only drawing a single frame), you can probably just use a basic loop instead of the `draw()` function.

Instead, try something like this:

```
boolean running = true;
while(running){
  // do your processing
  if(done){
    running = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I tried using "thread()" with this and just ' "draw()" 'ed ' like only the best set of weights. And then used multiple threads to try a bunch of scenarios simultaneously?

Comment: @DontJudgeMe Only use threads if you know what you're doing. Processing is not thread safe, and you should only draw from Processing's main thread.

Comment: Doing this and running it on just a single other thread worked flawlessly perfectly, thanks.